# how to update homepage with data from other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller

Currently my homepage shows data from  different models which are articles,forums.

The code I have written shows the data from different model but not according to date and time at which they are created. I mean data from articles is getting displayed according to date and time,same with polls  but not as a whole i.e if an article is created before a poll its not displayed before poll.

This is because I have written articles code after poll and in the controller I am using different variables to retrieve data from different models and in the view I am looping through theses variables as follows.

The code for controller of this homepage is

```
def index
  @col     = Education.select(:college_id).where(user_id: @current_user.id).all
  @users   = Education.select(:user_id).where(college_id: @col.collect(&:college_id)).all 

  @poll    = Poll.where(created_by: @users.collect(&:user_id)).all
  @article = Article.where(user_id: @users.collect(&:user_id)).all

end
```

and in index view page i have written following code

```
        - unless @poll.empty?
            -  @poll.reverse.each do | poll|
                #statusbox
                    .imgbox
                        - if User.find(poll.created_by).basic_info
                            - if User.find(poll.created_by).basic_info.profilephoto?
                                = image_tag User.find(poll.created_by).basic_info.profilephoto.url(:thumb)
                            - else
                                %span no img
                        - else
                            %span no img
                    #welcomeheader

                        %span.bl=User.find(poll.created_by).first_name
                        posted a poll
                        %span.bl= time_ago_in_words(poll.created_at)  
                        ago

                        %p=link_to poll.name,poll


                %br

        - unless @article.empty?
            -  @article.reverse.each do | article|
                #statusbox
                    .imgbox
                        - if User.find(article.user_id).basic_info
                            - if User.find(article.user_id).basic_info.profilephoto?
                                = image_tag User.find(article.user_id).basic_info.profilephoto.url(:thumb)
                            - else
                                %span no img
                        - else
                            %span no img
                    #welcomeheader

                        %span.bl=User.find(article.user_id).first_name
                        posted an article
                        %span.bl= time_ago_in_words(article.created_at)  
                        ago

                        %p=link_to article.name,article


                %br
```

**Is there a way where I can store data from these different models and store it in a single variable and den loop through it or any other way by which I can show updates date and timewise from other models in a single view**

Comment: There's way too much going on in your code :-( Can you please describe the problem statement in one sentence and highlight it with bold font?

Answer (score 1):

As I have seen in your code that for all 4 models you are showing same type of data, for that you can create a tableless model

```
class PostWrapper
    store_in nil
    belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => nil

    field :created_at, type: Time
    field :content, type: String
    filed :post_type, type: String
    and all other fields
end
```

you can assign values to object of these model and use it in view

Or

If your all the 4 models have some common attributes and behaviour then you can give a try on STI(single table inheritance) link(http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html) and then use the object of that table and use it in view accordingly.